# Neo4j - conditional execution

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have following application model with temporal network:
Kpi can have single Metric connected.

I want to achieve following logic using single query:

1. If kpi has already metric connected and old metric id = new metric id, then do nothing
2. If kpi has already metric connected and old metric id <> new metric id, then terminate previous connection (oldMetric.to = {now}) and create new connection between kpi and metric
3. If kpi doesn't have any metric connected, connect new metric.

In other words: break existing connection if exists, and create new one (+ do nothing when new connection equals to previous)

Here is my cypher:

```
match (kpi:KpiIN)  
where id(kpi) = {kpiId}  
optional match (kpi)-[currentRel:Indicates]->(currentMetric:MetricIN)  
where currentRel.to = {maxTime}  
optional match (newMetric:MetricIN)  
where id (newMetric) = {metricId}  
with kpi, currentMetric, newMetric, currentRel  
where COALESCE(id(currentMetric), -1) <> id(newMetric)  
foreach (toTerminate in  [x IN [currentRel] where x is not null] | set toTerminate.to = {now} ) 
create (kpi)-[:Indicates {props} ]->(newMetric)
```

Any option to make this query easier - especially foreach part where I actually check for null in current metric node.

Comment: 1) Have you considered using other identifiers than internal id? 2) I assume the `props` parameter contains a value for the `to` property: is this value the same as either `now` or `maxTime`?

Comment: Using other ids doesn't change much.
to = Long.MAX_VALUE
now = new DAte().getTime(),
maxTime = Long.MAX_VALUE

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work

```
MATCH (kpi:KpiIN {kpiId:{kpiId})
MERGE kpi-[r:INDICATES]->(m1:MetricIN {metricId:{metricId}})
    ON CREATE SET r = {props}, m1.created = 1
WITH kpi, m1
    WHERE HAS(m1.created)
MATCH kpi-[r:INDICATES]->(m2:MetricIN)
    WHERE m2.metricId <> {metricId}
SET r.to = {now}
REMOVE m1.created
```

It follows your parameters:

1. If same metric exists... – there is no `ON MATCH` clause in the `MERGE`
2. If different metric exists... – `ON CREATE` sets a temporary property and the tail, where "previous connection is terminated" executes only if that property exists
3. If no metric exists... – `MERGE` creates metric if not exists and `ON CREATE` sets the properties on `[:INDICATES]`

This approach would require that you abandon internal ids.

I wrote this query without a graph to test it on so I may have missed something. If you want to make it easier to answer your question you can create a sample graph at http://console.neo4j.org and add a link to your question.

Comment: Any option with using internal ids?